# Is the discrepancy in Turing's representation of complete configurations intentional?

Tags: turing-machines, history

On page 235 of [Turing's 1936 paper](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Erobins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf), in the figure marked (C), the illustration appears not to match the description. The description states that

> space has been made on the left of the scanned symbol, and the *m*-configuration written in its place

but the illustration (repeated on p. 242 using [SD encoding](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/turing-machine/#InteProgBehaNota)) shows no scanned symbol for the first complete configuration:

```
b:əəo0 0:əəq0 0: ...
```

It's hard to tell if this is meant to me something special about the starting state, or a general part of the representation so that one would have

```
b:əəo0 0:əəq0 0:əə0 q0:əə0 0 q:əə0 0p 1:əə0p 0 1:əpə0 0 1:...
```

rather than the representation corresponding to the description:

```
b :əəo0 0:əəq0 0:əə0 q0:əə0 0 q :əə0 0p 1:əə0p 0 1:əpə0 0 1:...
```

Is there significance to this discrepancy? Is it intentional?